# javax.rms.MarshallException : Missing Soap Body or Envelope

Tags: java, web-services, java-me, wsdl, marshalling

I am trying to call service from my midlet but it gives me exception **javax.rms.MarshallException** : Missing Soap Body or Envelope.**It works fine in emulator**. but when i try this on my nokia c1 it throws an exception. Is there any problem with my wsdl file or anything else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the server resolved the issue as i was using jetty server but it was giving me this error. the i migrated to glassfish server and resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error `javax.rms.MarshallException` because you are accessing web service. For accessing web service you need **JSR 172** API. I believe s40 Series mobile doesn't have that support. ( Background : I tried to searching on google "[Nokia C1-00 Specification](http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sugexp=les;&gs_nf=1&pq=j2me+rest%20api&cp=25&gs_id=b1&xhr=t&q=Nokia%20C1-00%20Specifications&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=Nokia+C1-00+Specification&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=16c18e40320a1066&biw=1600&bih=787)" and show the result, there was no JSR 172 API support found. )

So to overcome this situation you need to convert your web service code using **[Rest API](http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=J2ME+Rest+api&oq=J2ME+Rest+api&gs_l=hp.3..0i30j0i8i30.439199.443298.6.443777.14.11.3.0.0.0.398.2763.0j1j9j1.11.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.ZI6YgXF7nis&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=16c18e40320a1066&biw=1600&bih=787)**.